# Using rkt with kubernetes causes "unsupported CRI runtime"

Tags: kubernetes

I am currently trying to set up a bare metal kubernetes cluster and I am using CoreOS Container Linux and facing the following issue when trying to start the kubelet service:

> server.go:266] failed to run Kubelet: failed to create kubelet: unsupported CRI runtime: "rkt"

My ignition file [Source](https://vadosware.io/post/k8s-container-linux-ignition-with-rkt-and-kube-router/):

```
# NOTE: This configuration is meant to work with Config Transpiler v0.8.0
# The spec is available at (https://github.com/coreos/container-linux-config-transpiler/blob/v0.8.0/doc/configuration.md)

passwd:
  users:
    - name: core
      ssh_authorized_keys:
        - ssh-rsa ...
systemd:
  units:
    # Docker will be configured initially but we'll be using rkt exclusively and will disable it after containerd setup
    - name: docker.service
      enabled: true

    ####################
    # services for rkt #
    ####################
    - name: rkt-api.service
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Description=rkt api service
        Documentation=http://github.com/rkt/rkt
        After=network.target rkt-api-tcp.socket
        Requires=rkt-api-tcp.socket

        [Service]
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/rkt api-service

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target

    - name: rkt-api-tcp.socket
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Description=rkt api service socket
        PartOf=rkt-api.service

        [Socket]
        ListenStream=127.0.0.1:15441
        ListenStream=[::1]:15441
        Service=rkt-api.service
        BindIPv6Only=both

        [Install]
        WantedBy=sockets.target

    - name: rkt-gc.service
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Garbage Collection for rkt

        [Service]
        Environment=GRACE_PERIOD=24h
        Type=oneshot
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/rkt gc --grace-period=${GRACE_PERIOD}

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target

    - name: rkt-gc.timer
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Periodic Garbage Collection for rkt

        [Timer]
        OnActiveSec=0s
        OnUnitActiveSec=12h

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target

    - name: rkt-metadata.service
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Description=rkt metadata service
        Documentation=http://github.com/rkt/rkt
        After=network.target rkt-metadata.socket
        Requires=rkt-metadata.socket

        [Service]
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/rkt metadata-service

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target

    - name: rkt-metadata.socket
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Description=rkt metadata service socket
        PartOf=rkt-metadata.service

        [Socket]
        ListenStream=/run/rkt/metadata-svc.sock
        SocketMode=0660
        SocketUser=root
        SocketGroup=root
        RemoveOnStop=true

        [Install]
        WantedBy=sockets.target

    ################################
    # services for install scripts #
    ################################
    - name: k8s-install.service
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target

        [Unit]
        Description=k8s installation script
        Wants=network-online.target
        After=network.target network-online.target

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        ExecStart=/ignition/init/k8s/install.sh

    - name: cni-install.service
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target

        [Unit]
        Description=cni plugin installation script
        Requires=k8s-install.service
        After=k8s-install.service

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        ExecStart=/ignition/init/cni/install.sh

    - name: rkt-setup.service
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target

        [Unit]
        Description=rkt installation script
        Requires=cni-install.service
        After=cni-install.service

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        ExecStart=/ignition/init/rkt/setup.sh

    - name: kubeadm-install.service
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target

        [Unit]
        Description=kubeadm installation script
        Requires=rkt-setup.service
        After=rkt-setup.service

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        Environment="PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/bin"
        ExecStart=/ignition/init/kubeadm/kubeadm-install.sh

    - name: k8s-setup.service
      enabled: true
      contents: |
        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target

        [Unit]
        Description=kubernetes setup script
        Requires=kubeadm-install.service
        After=kubeadm-install.service

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        User=core
        Environment="PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/bin"
        ExecStart=/ignition/init/k8s/setup.sh

storage:
  filesystems:
    - mount:
        device: /dev/disk/by-label/ROOT
        format: xfs
        wipe_filesystem: true
        label: ROOT

  files:
    - path: /opt/bin/kubeadm
      filesystem: root
      mode: 493 # 0755
      contents:
        remote:
          url: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.14.3/bin/linux/amd64/kubeadm

    - path: /opt/bin/kubelet
      filesystem: root
      mode: 493 # 0755
      contents:
        remote:
          url: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.14.3/bin/linux/amd64/kubelet

    - path: /opt/bin/kubectl
      filesystem: root
      mode: 511 # 0777
      contents:
        remote:
          url: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.14.3/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl

    - path: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service
      filesystem: root
      mode: 420 # 0644
      contents:
        remote:
          url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/v1.14.3/build/debs/kubelet.service

    - path: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
      filesystem: root
      mode: 420 # 0644
      contents:
        remote:
          url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/v1.14.3/build/debs/10-kubeadm.conf

    - path: /ignition/init/cni/cni-plugins-v0.8.1.tgz
      filesystem: root
      mode: 420 # 0644
      contents:
        remote:
          url: https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/releases/download/v0.8.1/cni-plugins-linux-amd64-v0.8.1.tgz

    - path: /ignition/init/canal/canal.yaml
      filesystem: root
      mode: 493 # 0755
      contents:
        remote:
          url: https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.7/manifests/canal.yaml

    - path: /ignition/init/kube-router/kube-router.yaml
      filesystem: root
      mode: 493 # 0755
      contents:
        remote:
          url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cloudnativelabs/kube-router/v0.3.1/daemonset/kubeadm-kuberouter.yaml

    - path: /ignition/init/k8s/install.sh
      filesystem: root
      mode: 480 # 740
      contents:
        inline: |
          #!/bin/bash

          # Unzip the kubernetes binaries if not already present
          test -d /opt/bin/kubeadm && echo "k8s binaries (kubeadm) already installed" && exit 0

          # NOTE: If RELEASE is updated, the SHA512 SUMs will need to be as well
          echo -e "=> Installing k8s v1.14.3"

          echo "=> Cusomizing kubelet.service..."
          sed -i "s:/usr/bin:/opt/bin:g" /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service
          sed -i "s:/usr/bin:/opt/bin:g" /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf

          systemctl daemon-reload
          systemctl enable kubelet
          systemctl start kubelet

    - filesystem: root
      path: /ignition/init/rkt/setup.sh
      mode: 480 # 740
      contents:
        inline: |
          #!/bin/bash

          # Unzip the kubernetes binaries if not already present
          test -d /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/0-kubelet-extra-args.conf && echo "rkt systemd drop-ins already installed" && exit 0

          echo "=> Adding dropins for rkt...."
          cat > /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/0-kubelet-extra-args.conf <<EOF
          [Service]
          Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--container-runtime=rkt --volume-plugin-dir=/var/lib/kubelet/volumeplugins"
          EOF

          echo "=> Triggering systemctl daemon-reload...."
          systemctl daemon-reload
          systemctl enable rkt-api
          systemctl enable rkt-metadata
          systemctl start rkt-api
          systemctl start rkt-metadata
          systemctl start rkt-gc

    - filesystem: root
      path: /ignition/init/cni/install.sh
      mode: 480 # 740
      contents:
        inline: |
          #!/bin/bash

          # Unzip the kubernetes binaries if not already present
          test -d /opt/cni/bin && echo "CNI binaries already installed" && exit 0

          VERSION=0.8.1
          echo -e "=> Installing CNI (v${VERSION}) binaries to /opt/cni/bin"
          cd /ignition/init/cni
          mkdir -p /opt/cni/bin
          tar -C /opt/cni/bin -k -xzf cni-plugins-v${VERSION}.tgz

    - filesystem: root
      path: /ignition/init/kubeadm/kubeadm-install.sh
      mode: 480 # 740
      contents:
        inline: |
          #!/bin/bash

          # Ensure kubeadm binary is present
          test -f /opt/bin/kubeadm || (echo "Failed to find kubeadm binary" && exit 1)

          # Exit if kubeadm has already been run (/etc/kubernetes folder would have been created)
          test -d /etc/kubernetes && echo "/etc/kubernetes is present, kubeadm should have already been run once" && exit 0

          echo "=> Running kubeadm init..."
          /opt/bin/kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr "10.244.0.0/16"

          echo "=> Running kubeadm post-install set up for user 'core'"
          mkdir -p /home/core/.kube
          cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /home/core/.kube/config
          chown $(id -u core):$(id -g core) /home/core/.kube/config

    - filesystem: root
      path: /ignition/init/k8s/setup.sh
      mode: 493 # 0755
      contents:
        inline: |
          #!/bin/bash

          # Ensure /etc/kubernetes is present (created by kubeadm)
          test -d /etc/kubernetes || (echo "/etc/kubernetes not present, ensure kubeadm has run properly" && exit 1)

          test -f /home/core/.kubernetes-setup-finished && echo "kubeadm already run, k8s should be set up" && exit 0

          echo "=> Enabling workload running on the master node"
          kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-

          echo "=> Installing kube-router"
          kubectl apply -f /ignition/init/kube-router/kube-router.yaml

          echo "=> Removing kube-proxy (kube-router will perform routing for the node)"
          kubectl delete daemonset kube-proxy -n kube-system
          docker run --privileged --net=host k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy-amd64:v1.14.3 kube-proxy --cleanup

          # Disable docker (it won't be used by anything after now)
          sudo systemctl stop docker
          sudo systemctl disable docker

          echo "=> Leaving post-setup lock file @ [/home/core/.kubernetes-setup-finished]"
          touch /home/core/.kubernetes-setup-finished

    - filesystem: root
      path: /etc/cni/net.d/10-kuberouter.conf
      mode: 493 # 0755
      contents:
        inline: |
          {
            "name":"kubernetes",
            "type":"bridge",
            "bridge":"kube-bridge",
            "isDefaultGateway":true,
            "ipam": {
              "type":"host-local"
            }
          }
```

Why is it not working? Does kubelet not support rkt anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

```
kubelet --help
```

> --container-runtime string
>   The container runtime to use. Possible values: 'docker', 'remote', 'rkt (deprecated)'. (default "docker")